# i changed my minecraft username and now i cant go on servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I logged off and on again also restarted my computer two times and it still doesn't work. I searched up what to do and none of it worked I even changed my skin.

Comment: Does any error message display on your screen when you try to connect?

Comment: no when I connect it says not authenticated with minecraft.net

Comment: You seem to have done the things that websites have recommended one should try in a situation like this. This quote from a Mineplex thread may help: "Make sure you goto the launcher and log off your old username. And log back in with the email you signed up with Minecraft."

Comment: how do I log off my old username? sorry and if you mean the log out and log on ive done that too many times to count

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could do is check Minecraft.net and go to account. Log OUT of you current Minecraft account and relog, this should fix the error

Answer (score -4):

He is what I did to fix the "I can't join" problem:

- Restart your computer
- Contact mojang staff members

This worked for me, I've changed my username every 30 days, and his happened every time

Comment: Perhaps tell him what they told you to do to fix the issue?